# Login en PHP MYSQL Undefined index: Clave

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Estoy haciendo un login con Usuario y Clave... Me manda este error: >

> Notice: Undefined index: Clave in C:\xampp\htdocs\Tarea_Semana_11\Validar.php on line 6

LINEA DE ERROR: `$Clave=$_POST['Clave'];`

Este es el codigo PHP:

```
<?php
//require('conexion.php');

$Usuario = $_POST['Usuario'];
$Clave = $_POST['Clave'];

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","practica_semana_11");
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE Usuario='$Usuario' and Clave='$Clave'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

$filas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);


if($filas> 0){
    header ("Location:Bienvenido.html");
}else{
    $error = "Error en la Autentificación";

}
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

el HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title>Universidad</title>
    <meta charset="uft-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
</head>
<body>

    <center><h1>Registro e informacion de Matricula</h1></center>
    <h1 class="h1" style="color:red">LOGIN</h1>
    <p></p>
    <form method="POST" action="Validar.php">
            <input type="text" placeholder="&#128272; Usuario" name="Usuario">
            <input type="password" placeholder="&#128272; Contraseña" name="Clave">
            <input type="submit" value="Ingresar">
            </form>     
            <div style= "font-size:16px; color:#cc0000;"><?php echo isset($error) ? utf8_decode($error) : '';?></div>
    <p></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Prueba cerrando cada INPUT y/o asignado el "id" con el mismo nombre; ejm: <input type="text" placeholder="&#128272; Usuario" name="Usuario"> --> <input type="text" placeholder="&#128272; Usuario" name="Usuario" /> o <input type="text" placeholder="&#128272; Usuario" name="Usuario" id="Usuario" />

Comment: Clave está bien definida en el formulario, debería enviarse en el `$_POST[]`... Me suena a un problema con la ruta de los archivos por lo que `Clave` no se está enviando en el POST. En el formulario HTML tienes esto:    `<form method="POST" action="Validar.php">` ¿Validar está en la misma carpeta en que se encuentra tu archivo HTML, el del formulario?

Answer (score 1):

¿Es posible que tu variable $Clave no esté definida?

Prueba a hacer lo siguiente:

```
if(isset($_POST['Clave'])){
    $Clave= $_POST['Clave'];
}
if(isset($Clave)){ 
    echo $Clave;
}
```

Comprueba que `$Clave` esté definida y si es así lo asignas a tu sql.

Answer (score 0):

Tu codigo deberiua primero comprobar que se este accediendo al script por un formulario tipo POST para que se ejecute el resto del codigo, deberia quedar algo asi.

```
<?php
//require('conexion.php');
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $Usuario = $_POST['Usuario'];
    $Clave = $_POST['Clave'];

    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","practica_semana_11");
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE Usuario='$Usuario' and Clave='$Clave'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

    $filas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);


    if($filas> 0){
        header ("Location:Bienvenido.html");
    }else{
        $error = "Error en la Autentificación";

    }
    mysqli_free_result($resultado);
    mysqli_close($conexion);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

La variable `$_POST['Clave']` no está definida.

esto puede ser por que estas abriendo la pagina directamente en el explorador, o por que al ejecutar el formulario no enviás el valor Clave.

debes validar la variable antes de usarla ya sea con isset o empty o cambiar el nivel de error_reporting en la configuración de php para que no muestre errores de tipo notice.

http://php.net/manual/es/function.error-reporting.php

esto lo puedes hacer en la configuración del servidor o en el archivo php